# why d3 scaleTime doesn't match its axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two scales like below.

The `scaleLinear` domain starts with 0 and ends with 18 and renders with those start and end values.

The domain of `scaleTime` is 2021-05-19 to 2021-06-01 but the axis doesn't begin with 2021-05-19 and end with 2021-06-01.

Why doesn't `scaleTime`'s axis match domain as `scaleLinear` does?

```js
var x1=d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date('2021-05-19'),new Date('2021-06-01')]).range([45,715]);
d3.select('svg').append("g").attr("transform","translate(0,100)").call(d3.axisBottom(x1));

var x2=d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,18]).range([45,715]);
d3.select('svg').append("g").attr("transform","translate(0,200)").call(d3.axisBottom(x2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <svg height=300 width=750></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try `[new Date('2021-05-19 00:00:00'),new Date('2021-06-02 00:00:00')]` ?